# Method argument in Python Path

Tags: python, path

Feels like a dumb question - but I am stuck.  Passing a method argument in a Python path is needed.

Example:

`def get_address(number):
    address = request_to_path('/customer/(\d+)/address') 
    return address`

Now, I can put a regular number where the (\d+) is located, and everything works fine as it should.  My issue is to actually pass the *number* in the get_address method to the path to make it automated and dynamic.

Easy solution?

Comment: what is a regular number?

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like

```
def get_address(number):
    address = request_to_path('/customer/%s/address' % number) 
    return address
```

You can use printf-style formatting or `.format()`. [This](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html) is a decent introduction.

Comment: Wonderful! I would appreciate it if you would accept my answer.